# initial-value-problem

Tags: initial-value-problems

I have the following IVP (Initial value problem, Cauchy-Problem), and I do not know how to solve this.

$$y'=e^{-x}-\frac{y}{x} \qquad \qquad y(1)=2$$

I hope you can help me, cause I really do not know how to start.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Use the fact that this is a separable ODE.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac yx&=e^{-x}\\
&\text{IF:}e^{\int\frac1xdx}=x\\
&yx=\int xe^{-x}dx\\
&=-(x+1)e^{-x}+c\\
&\text{putting the initial value $x=1,y=2$}\\
&2=-2e^{-1}+c\\
&c=2+\frac2e\\
&\text{our Ans is: $yx=-(x+1)e^{-x}+2+\frac2e$}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

First, one need to solve the homogeneous differential equation associated to the original equation, that is:
$$
y'=-\dfrac{y}{x}
$$
We have
\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{y'}{y}&=&-\dfrac1x\\
\int\dfrac{dy}{y}&=&-\int\dfrac{dx}{x}\\
\ln|y|&=&\ln|C|-\ln|x|\\
y&=&\dfrac{A}{x}.
\end{eqnarray}
Now, we use the variation of constants:
$$
y'=\dfrac{A'}{x}-\dfrac{A}{x^2}=e^{-x}-\dfrac{A}{x^2},
$$
therefore
$$
A'=xe^{-x},
$$
and using integration by parts we get
$$
A=\int xe^{-x}\,dx=-xe^{-x}+\int e^{-x}\,dx=-xe^{-x}-e^{-x}+B=-(x+1)e^{-x}+B
$$
We deduce that
$$
y=-\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)e^{-x}+\dfrac{B}{x}.
$$
using the initial condition $y(1)=2$, we deduce that 
$$
B=2+2e^{-1},
$$
thus
$$
y=-\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)e^{-x}+\dfrac{2+2e^{-1}}{x}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{x}=e^{-x} \tag{1}$$
This is a first order linear ODE. Hence, we can either use an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) or use [Variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#First_order_equation) (see "First order equation").

If you want to use an integrating factor, it will be:

$$\mu(x)=e^{\int \frac{1}{x}~dx}=x$$

Multiply equation $(1)$ by $\mu(x)$:

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=\frac{x}{e^x}$$

If you still cannot solve it, feel free to let us know.